# Laravel controller return to route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm running a query within my controller which returns a callback url I would like to set this url to be my home controller so I can work with the data thats returned on the callback.

```
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://myapp.app/home', $permissions);
```

I would like this url to be the controller of my route, currently this path returns the correct data in the url however I get the following error -

```
Cross-site request forgery validation failed. The "state" param from the URL and session do not match.
```

Is there a way to return the url back without getting a `CSRF` error.

Answer (score 0):

from App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php

you can define a rule that exclude csrf urls like:

```
protected $except = [
    'vips/pay-result',
    'wechat/access-entrance',
    'wechat-mp/callback',
    'admin/announcements_image_upload'
];
```

Comment: Can you wildcard the exception e.g. '/home?*'

Comment: @SamXronn, no you can check parent class , it don't check pregs

Answer (score 0):

My CSRF issue was referring to the session it was trying to use when the callback happened.

Inside `bootstrap/app.php` I just started a session right at the top before the app was returned e.g.

```
session_start();
```